# Setting up apache2 on ubuntu to avoid index.php in joomla

Tags: 14.04, apache2, .htaccess

I have an ubuntu 14.04 azure virtual machine serving a couple of different sites.

www.example.com is set up to ip 1.2.3.4 (my server) and is redirected to 1.2.3.4/example. This works fine.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.example.com
        ServerAlias example.com
        DocumentRoot /usr/share/example
</VirtualHost>
```

The actual joomla installation is placed in /usr/share/example (it is actually a link to /mounteddrive/example).

When I turn on URL rewriting in joomla to avoid index.php being a part of the URL it fails (404 page is coming up).

I have made the following changes to .htaccess which I have made sure to copy from the original 3.4.1 joomla before making the lastest changes.

(And I have remembered to clear the caches ;-))

```
## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
#
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*(index|home)\.html?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)(index|home)\.html?$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
#
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}>s ^(443>(s)|[0-9]+>s)$
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.php$ http%2://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.example\.com)?$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
## End - Custom redirects
```

I have a feeling that I need to also do something about `RewriteBase /` in this case but not sure what.

I have looked at several ressources on the specific joomla issues, but seem to run into things being set up slightly different than in the ubuntu distribution, this is why I ask here.

Comment: The problem turned out to be an AllowOverride None directive blocking the .htaccess file. The solution was to add

<Directory /usr/share/example>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

Answer (score 1):

The mod_rewrite is required to be enabled in apache. You can try this:

http://www.dev-metal.com/enable-mod_rewrite-ubuntu-14-04-lts/

Comment: Hi @Isaac. Mod_rewrite was already enabled. The changes to 000-default.conf mentioned in the link did not help either. I think it is more an issue of joomla being in a subdirectory and example.com being sent there via a VirtualHost directive.

Comment: Hi again. The culprit was an AllowOverride directive. Your link send me down the right track. Thanks.